# Whats wrong with my JavaScript architecture (YUI3)?

Tags: javascript, yui3

I am writing a web application which uses YUI3 for all it's JS needs. I need functionality such as Tooltips, Tooltips whose content is determined by AJAX queries, Toggle Buttons and so on.

I was not sure who to build an architecture to achieve all this. I have taken the following approach

```
var Myapp = function(){

    this.toggleButton(node,config)
    {
        YUI().use(....,function(Y){
            //code to convert NODE into a toggle button;

        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

In my application I then just convert all the buttons into toggle buttons by calling

```
var app = Myapp(); 
app.toggleButton(Y.all('.toggle-buttons'),{'text1':'TOGGLE_ME','text2':'TOGGLED_ME'});
```

All this works. But I wanted to know from more experienced developers if there is anything fundamentally wrong with this approach.

Is this a good way to use JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return this;`

This is unneccesary since function constructors return `this` by default.

`var app = Myapp();`

You forgot to call `new Myapp()` without the `new` keyword `this` will be the window object and you are effectively writing to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental problem in your code:

```
var MyApp = function(){

    this.toggleButton(node,config)
    {
     ...
```

You're not defining a function for `MyApp`. Instead, you try to invoke *toggleButton* each time you instantiate it. It should fail because the function is ***undefined***

---

In your case, Class definition and instantiation is not needed because `MyApp` is being used as a utility.

You can define `MyApp` as a static Object:

```
var MyApp = {
    toggleButton: function toggleButton() {
        // your code
    }
};
```

And you can use it anywhere by:

```
MyApp.toggleButton();
```